# Call Update-Package for different solution file

Tags: powershell, visual-studio, nuget, package-manager-console, nuget-update

I have a powershell script that I launch from Package Manager Console in Visual studio.
In particular I have a question related to this command:

```
 Update-Package -ProjectName $ProjectName -reinstall
```

This command installs packages from `packages.config` (I'm working mainly with legacy non sdk projects) into specified project.

All is good when I run this command for projects in the currently opened solution. But I don't want opening many solutions to update packages, instead I wrote a single script (called inside package manager in VS) that just goes into specific solution folder and update projects there. It works, but the generated paths to `packages` folder in .csproj file are created relative to the initially opened solution, not the solution where the particular project belongs to. Which leads to paths like:

```
   ..\..\..\..\SomeNotCurrentlyOpenedSolution\packages\..
```

instead just

```
   ..\packages\..
```

Is there a way to fix it? Maybe somehow it's possible to force VS thinking that a particular command is launched for specified solution, not always currently opened

**UPDATE1:**
Please see commands log and description:

To illustrate the issue I have 2 newly created empty solutions: `ClassLibrary1.sln` and `ClassLibrary2.sln`. `ClassLibrary1.csproj` (a single project inside solution) has a reference on `newtonsoft` package. I've opened `Package Manager Console` in `ClassLibrary2.sln` and type the below commands:

```
PM> ls
    Directory: C:\test\ClassLibrary2
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                              
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                              
d-----          3/9/2024   9:53 PM                ClassLibrary2                                                                     
-a----          3/9/2024   9:53 PM           1145 ClassLibrary2.sln                                                                 

PM> Get-Content ..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
...
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
...
```

As we can see, the `ClassLibrary1.csproj` has a reference on `Newtonesoft.Json` package with expected path.

As suggested by @jdweng, I've `cd`ed into `ClassLibrary1.csproj`.

```
PM> cd ..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1

PM> ls
    Directory: C:\test\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                              
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                              
d-----          3/9/2024   9:28 PM                bin                                                                               
d-----          3/9/2024   9:28 PM                obj                                                                               
d-----          3/9/2024   9:28 PM                Properties                                                                        
-a----          3/9/2024   9:28 PM            196 Class1.cs                                                                         
-a----          3/9/2024   9:30 PM           2528 ClassLibrary1.csproj                                                              
-a----          3/9/2024   9:30 PM            144 packages.config
```

and try to update packages in `ClassLibrary1.csproj`. It doesn't work until I add a `ClassLibrary1.csproj` project into `ClassLibrary2` solution (that's fine to me).

```
PM> Update-Package -ProjectName ClassLibrary1 -reinstall
Update-Package : Project 'ClassLibrary1' is not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Package -ProjectName ClassLibrary1 -reinstall
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ClassLibrary1:String) [Update-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

after adding the ClassLibrary1.csproj project into the ClassLibrary2 solution, the command has succeded:

```
PM> ls
    Directory: C:\test\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                              
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                              
d-----          3/9/2024  10:02 PM                bin                                                                               
d-----          3/9/2024   9:28 PM                obj                                                                               
d-----          3/9/2024   9:28 PM                Properties                                                                        
-a----          3/9/2024   9:28 PM            196 Class1.cs                                                                         
-a----          3/9/2024  10:12 PM           2278 ClassLibrary1.csproj                                                              
-a----          3/9/2024  10:12 PM            144 packages.config                                                                   

PM> Update-Package -ProjectName ClassLibrary1 -reinstall

Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project 'ClassLibrary1', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Gathering dependency information took 216 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions install multiple packages
Retrieving package 'Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.3' from 'nuget.org'.
Removed package 'Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.3' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.3' from ClassLibrary1
Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.3' already exists in folder 'C:\test\ClassLibrary2\packages'
Added package 'Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.3' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.3' to ClassLibrary1
Executing nuget actions took 718 ms
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.9501830

PM> Get-Content .\ClassLibrary1.csproj
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\ClassLibrary2\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

you may see that the path to `Newtonsoft.Json` binaries has been changed. How can I prevent it?

For the context, what I want to do is to install packages mentioned in `packages.config` into the project file.

**UPDATE2:**

I tried approach suggested by @VonC related to nuget.exe binary:

```
nuget restore YourSolution.sln
```

or

```
nuget update YourProject.csproj
```

Unfortunatelly, it doesn't update neither a project file nor `package.config`. For now, using package manager console, I install a new package via:

```
  Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 7.0.1
```

of if the package is already in packages.config run (yeah, it's weird case):

```
  Update-Package -ProjectName $ProjectName -reinstall
```

As far as I can tell, `nuget restore` or `nuget update` does nothing with `packages.config` and project file

Comment: You need to use CD and move to the folder.

Comment: @jdweng, it doesn't look working, please see updates

Comment: I often edit the csproj files and change absolute paths to relative paths.  I like making backups of large projects.   So I have main project and child projects in a root folder.  Than I simply make copies of Root for backups.  For this to work, the reference from main project to child project has to be relative.  So I edit the main project csproj and remove absolute reference and make them relative.  Everything than works great.  I think you need to do similar.

Comment: @jdweng, in this case, paths are relative, just not standard. For the context, I need to create nuget packages from these projects with not "standard paths to packages folder", as far as I can tell, it won't give any harm (at least I didn't find anything "not standard paths to packages folder" related in the generated nugets). So maybe I can leave it as is, but still would be good to fix it if possible

Comment: you are mixing the terms project and solution. A solution is a set of projects and the file name ends with .sln, a project is a class library and the file name ends with .csproj for c# libraries. Moreover you should specify which version of Update-Package  you are using. It's pretty hard to understand what it does from your description.

Comment: @MarcoMerola, `you are mixing the terms project and solution` => no, I don't do it. I've added few clarifications that may help to clearely see the step.

Comment: `. It's pretty hard to understand what it does from your description.` => the answer on this is in the last part of my question, in particular I want to install packages added into `package.json` (by different command) into project file without long relative paths to a solution where I've launched the script from

Comment: what if you change the hint path to use solutionDir as mentioned here: https://yer.ac/blog/2019/11/20/identifying-nuget-package-references-which-are-using-relative-paths-across-whole-solution/

Comment: So that all hint paths in your csproj start with "$(SolutionDir)packages\" instead of the relative path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Update-Package` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-update-package) in the [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell) operates within the context of the currently loaded solution in Visual Studio. When you add a project from another solution and update its packages, NuGet resolves the paths based on the *current* solution's directory, which leads to the undesired path changes you have observed.

Unfortunately, directly manipulating the solution context from within the Package Manager Console to trick Visual Studio into thinking a different solution is loaded for the scope of the command is not straightforward or supported by existing NuGet PowerShell commands.

---

That means you would have to consider, as an alternative, to automate package updates with the NuGet Command Line Interface (CLI) or MSBuild. Both tools can be used *outside* of Visual Studio and allow you to specify the solution or project files explicitly. That would give you more control over the process and avoids the context issue with Visual Studio's Package Manager Console.

For example, using the NuGet CLI, you can restore packages for a specific solution or project file without opening it in Visual Studio:

```bash
nuget restore YourSolution.sln
```

Or update packages for a project:

```bash
nuget update YourProject.csproj
```

---

As a more straightforward workaround, after updating the packages, you could manually adjust the [`HintPath` in the `.csproj`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#reference) files using a script. While not ideal, this would allow you to correct the paths without manually editing each file. You could write a PowerShell script to search and replace incorrect path segments in your project files.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csproj | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName).replace('..\..\ClassLibrary2\packages', '..\packages') | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

That script finds all `.csproj` files, reads their content, replaces the incorrect relative path with the correct one, and saves the file.

---

[Marco Merola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13845498/marco-merola)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78130076/call-update-package-for-different-solution-file?noredirect=1#comment137755929_78130076) expands on the last workaround, changing the `HintPath` to use `$(SolutionDir)` instead of relative paths directly in your `.csproj` files: your project would reference the NuGet packages relative to the solution directory, regardless of where the project is being built from.

For existing references in your `.csproj` files, you would need to manually edit them or write a script to replace the relative paths with `$(SolutionDir)packages\`. For example, a `<HintPath>` that looks like `..\..\packages\MyPackage\lib\net45\MyLib.dll` would be changed to `$(SolutionDir)packages\MyPackage\lib\net45\MyLib.dll`.

The script mentioned in the blog post "[Identifying Nuget package references which are using relative paths across whole solution](https://yer.ac/blog/2019/11/20/identifying-nuget-package-references-which-are-using-relative-paths-across-whole-solution/)" from [yer.ac](https://dev.to/yerac) can be a starting point for automating the process of identifying and updating project references that do not use `$(SolutionDir)`.

```
param (
    [string]$solutionDir
)

$solutionDir = $solutionDir -replace '\\$', '' # Make sure no trailing backslash
$csprojFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $solutionDir -Recurse -Filter *.csproj

foreach ($file in $csprojFiles) {
    $content = Get-Content $file.FullName
    $updated = $false

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Length; $i++) {
        if ($content[$i] -match '<HintPath>[^$](.*?packages\\)') {
            $content[$i] = $content[$i] -replace '<HintPath>[^$].*?packages\\', "<HintPath>$(`$SolutionDir)packages\\"
            $updated = $true
        }
    }

    if ($updated) {
        $content | Set-Content $file.FullName
        Write-Output "Updated HintPath in $($file.FullName)"
    }
}
```

You can run this script for a specific solution directory by providing the path to the solution directory as an argument. It searches for `.csproj` files, looks for `HintPath` entries without `$(SolutionDir)`, and replaces them with paths that start with `$(SolutionDir)packages\`.

To make this process even easier, you can incorporate the PowerShell script as an External Tool in Visual Studio, as described in the blog post. That allows you to run the script directly from Visual Studio for the currently opened solution, helping you make sure all project references use the `$(SolutionDir)` variable for package paths.

Comment: thanks @VonC for your answer. Unfortunatelly I don't want making changes in the project files, so $SolutionDir doesn't really work to me. Approach with `nuget restore` and `nuget update` looks like useless too. So far, I don't understand these commands since it looks like they do not affect anything in the project and definitelly doesn't update project file

Comment: I will think about updating paths in the script

Comment: @Unnamed I agree: updating paths with a script should be a more practical solution.

Comment: @Unnamed `nuget restore` looks at the packages listed in either `packages.config` or the project file (for SDK-style projects) and downloads and installs any missing packages into the `packages` directory. It does not modify `packages.config` or the project file (.csproj). Its primary purpose is to ensure that all the packages required by the project are available, but it won't attempt to update them to newer versions.

Comment: @Unnamed When you run `nuget update YourProject.csproj`, it attempts to update the packages referenced in the project file to the latest versions based on the constraints defined in `packages.config`. However, it will not add or remove package references in `packages.config` or the project file. If the versions specified in `packages.config` are already the latest within the defined constraints, it may appear as if the command does nothing.

Comment: "nuget update" behaves differently than Update-Package: "If an updated package has an added assembly, a new reference is not added. New package dependencies also don't have their assembly references added."

Comment: @VonC it's a bit strange that updating project file and `packages.config` (out of the box) can happen only with `Package Manager Console` and not with any other tool, but it looks like we have what we have, thanks

Comment: @MarcoMerola True, good point. The `Update-Package` command in Visual Studio's Package Manager Console is more integrated with Visual Studio's project system.